# Android kotlin preferences spinner with values from arrays.xml

Tags: kotlin

**settings_activity.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**root_preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference
        android:dialogTitle="Select bluetooth adapter"
        android:key="bluetoothName"
        android:summary="Click to show a list to choose from"
        android:title="Bluetooth adapter" />
    <ListPreference
        android:dialogTitle="Select units"
        android:entries="@array/units_names"
        android:entryValues="@array/units_values"
        android:key="units"
        android:summary="Click to show a list to choose from"
        android:title="Units" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**SettingsActivity.kt**

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        }
    }
}
```

**arrays.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="units_values">
        <item>miles</item>
        <item>km</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="units_names">
        <item>miles and mpg</item>
        <item>km and l/100km</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
...
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected( item: MenuItem) : Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.toolbar_item_settings -> {
                val intent: Intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                return true
            }
        }
        return true
    }
...
```

Why are the array values not showing in the spinner?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because the list item text colour has defaulted to black.

It needs:

```
<item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/text</item>
```